# google maps api, change icon triggers mouseover event

Tags: google-maps-api-3

I am using google maps 3 api and am changing the icon of a marker when it is clicked. I am also registered for mouseover and mouseout events on the marker. I am finding that when the icon is changed because it has been clicked, it triggers a mouseout and then a mouseover. Is there a way to prevent these extra events from triggering?

edit: I'm changing the icon with the following code:

marker.setIcon(selecticon);

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

How are you changing the icon? Are you sure you are not destroying the marker, and then recreating it.

We have no way of knowing because you haveing let us see your code (please include a link)